# append zero using sprintf with big values

Tags: php, printf

I need to append a number of zeros to a integer value,That number of zeros may be upto 20.

```
   echo sprintf("%020d",'123456789101112');
```

But i got the result

```
 00000000002147483647
```

This is wrong,I need to get 00000123456789101112,Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: You've got an integer overflow by using `decimal` in your format string. Have a look at [integer type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: Solved issue using str_pad,Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [str_pad](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$value = "123456789101112";
echo str_pad($value, 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Output**

```
00000123456789101112
```